# Activate a new logo within a div at certain width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I would like to have a different logo image when my site goes to tablet/mobile size. I figured the best way to do this is rather than have a img src within the div,  set the logo as a background image to my div/id.

When my page goes below 990px a different mobile logo is displayed.

This is what I have, it works but is this the correct way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/omca16oe/

```
    <div id="logo"><a href="/home"></a></div>

    #logo  {
        background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/O49APFa.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display:block;
        width:452px;
        height:62px;
    }

    @media (max-width:990px) {
    #logo  {
        background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/CNYdTsD.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display:block;
        width:452px;
        height:62px;
    }
    }
```

Comment: If it works...it's correct. Could you do it other ways...sure...but that doesn't make them any more correct.

Comment: it's ok to use this method just remove extra code which repeat again like width and height if it's same as desktop version and also background-repeat

Comment: Any other ways in how it could be done though? Perhaps CSS sprites?

Comment: Several ways but that's not the question. If it WAS your question it would be too broad and so off-topic.

Comment: @Paulie_D The question was "is this the correct way to do this?"

Comment: Which is asking for opinions...which is also off-topic. If it works it's correct. FWIW...it's the way I'd do it...but that's just my **opinion**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but usually you would use a mobile-first appropach in this case, because the desktop logos/images usually are larger and won't be loaded at all on mobile devices then (= reducing bandwidth), like:

```
#logo  {
            background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/CNYdTsD.jpg');/* mobile logo */
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display:block;
            width:452px;
            height:62px;
}
@media (min-width:991px) {
  #logo  {
            background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/O49APFa.jpg'); /* desktop logo */
  }
}
```

Also, avoid repetition of stuff that's already there (like "display: block" etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct way to solve this. There are other ways, but in my opinion this is probably the best.

But you can reduce the CSS

```
   <div id="logo"><a href="/home"></a></div>

#logo  {
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/O49APFa.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width:452px;
    height:62px;
}

@media (max-width:990px) {
    #logo  {
        background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/CNYdTsD.jpg');
    }
}
```

You are using the same CSS for different screens and this way you do not have unnecessary duplicate code.
Because you do not change the other values in the "@media.." block, they just stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to initialize logo size and then resize it for max screen and device width like follows. Make sure include a device width as well, for clarification on mobile devices.

```
#logo  {
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/O49APFa.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display:block;
width:452px;
height:62px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:500px) and (min-device-width : 768px) { 
    #logo {
      width:200px; 
      height:20px; 
    }  
}
```